# Mac OS X Mountain Lion kernel panic after installing latest steinberg sound card driver

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

I just bought a steinberg CI2 and went to their website to download the latest driver and when I installed it gave a kernel panic. I don't have any backups and is there a way to backup all the files on terminal ? (since I only can use terminal right now) 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: voting to close, belongs on superuser or askdifferent

Comment: Okay I fixed the writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to access the recovery function at boot (when powering on, hold Cmd+R until the Apple logo shows up). Once the recovery environment is completely booted up, you can access the Disk Utility to make a complete backup of your files, or save an image of the drive to copy files from. After your files are safe, it's probably easiest to just reinstall Mountain Lion and then put your files back on.